# how to show tooltip text as table for TreeView in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to implement a functionality in which when i click F2 on any Treeview item, it should display the Tooltip for that item (This is possible generally).But in Tooltip the text should be in tabular format and also should allow me to edit the value of the item text.

Please let me know if anyone has implemented this.
I am not sure whether its feasible or not...Please if anyone has any other idea which we can implement to achieve this functionality

Thanks,
Nikhil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tabular format is easy: tooltips accept html-formatted text. But I don't think you can make it editable.

Comment: Hi Tonyk, how i can show in tabular format with html formatted text..?? i have a data in map....

Comment: And here is an example from my own code: <table><tr><td width="50">Real:</td><td>Opens a real, physical card reader</td></tr><tr><td>Auto:</td><td>First Virtual; if that fails, then Real</td></tr><tr><td>Virtual:</td><td>Opens a Virtual Card Reader</td></tr></table>